# Generate Python templates with parameters

Tags: python, code-generation

I have used JET with Eclipse before to generate Java files from models. I am new to Python and I am searching for a way to generate python modules automatically based on parameters (data) read from the user -for educational purposes.

> For example, a student will be guided to a webpage, where he/she enters the name of a project, select different control statements (ie.a while loop), enter a boolean expression, and the loop body, and hit generate. The webpage will generate a .py module for him/her that could be used for educational purposes.

After research, I found many python generators out there, and I guess Jinja is one of the most popular ones. But I would like to know if I am going the right direction before making a decision.

So my questions are as:

1. What is the best python code generator that fits my project idea
   the most?
2. Should I build the web interface of such a project
   using a Python platform, or something else like PHP?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to generate Python code from a model you can try Telosys code generator : http://www.telosys.org/.

It allows to generate code for different kinds of languages including Python.

In your case I suggest to create a basic DSL model (or download the DSL model example from here http://www.telosys.org/download/models-v3/ ) and use the following templates for Python :

- Python REST with Bottle : https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/python-web-rest-bottle
- Python persistence with SQL alchemy : https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/python-persistence-sqlalchemy

The "CLI" version of Telosys is probably the best option (because it's independent from any IDE) : https://github.com/telosys-tools-bricks/telosys-cli/wiki